# Setting --evironment argument in update-database command in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to target a specific environment when running my `update-database` commands in the package manager console of my ASP.NET Core 5 WebApi.

My project is running `EF Core 5.0.5`.

Following the [EF Core tools reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) link, I can successfully run the command with

```
Update-Database -Args '--environment Production'
```

However, in my `CreateDbContext` method I am still getting the `development` environment variable instead of `production`.

```
public BCASDataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .MinimumLevel.Debug()
       .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
       .WriteTo.Console()
       .CreateLogger();

   // Get environment
   string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

   Log.Logger.Information($"Running the DbContext under '{environment}' environment.");
        
   // Build config using main API settings for Database
   IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../Services.WebApi"))
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
      .AddEnvironmentVariables()
      .Build();
```

My console output above is `Development` instead of `Production` as expected? Can anyone please advise me what I am doing wrong?

My aim is to be able to quickly run the migration without having to run a separate environment set prior to avoid any issues and accidentally targeting production for example.

Comment: Did you modify the windows envrionmental variable "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT".  Changing the varible value has nothing to do you your c# project.  You have to change a windows property.

Comment: No, from the documentation I assumed I didn't have to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli the link here the notes at the end suggest that I should be able to set this through the Args?

Comment: That is what is wrong.  If you rum from cmd.exe >Set you will get a list of the environmental variable and the settings.  You are using : string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

Comment: From what they [wrote in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#other), the environment variables seems to be always set as "Development". And you are supposed to use `string[] args` for performing conditional actions. Whatever is in these args seems to be up to you, including the parsing - they just deliver whatever is given to the command.

Comment: Yes, from further testing it does seem this way. As you say I have a work around where I can pull from the string[] args in the CreateDbContext method manually.

Comment: What about putting the command in a script (ps or bash) and set the environment there. Then you can invoke your script passing params, one being the environment name. That's what we use in our solution :)